# How Do I Change Pi-Hole's URL from 192.168.x.x:8080 to pi.hole?

Tags: pi-hole

I am running PiHole and HomeBridge on the same server and am looking to have 192.168.x.x:8080 forward to the PiHole by setting up a DNS record for pi.hole.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever modem/switch to create a static lease assigned to your pi hole's mac address

Another piece of information "192.168.x.x" is an ip not a url.

And "pi.hole" or any worded device name is call a hostname.

A URL is the line in the format `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id` .